# Given the polynomial: x^2 +ax + b. Find the roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

QUESTION:

Let (a,b) in $R^2$ be an arbitrary point on the plane.
We need to color it RED, WHITE, OR BLUE according to the following scheme:

- (a,b)is RED if $x^2 + ax + b $ has two different real roots.
- (a,b) is WHITE if $x^2 + ax + b$ has no real roots.
- (a,b) is BLUE if $x^2 + ax + b$ has a real root which occurs twice.

Color this plane according to the scheme(use colors) and give justification for your coloring.

[image: Problem and Grapth]

---

My attempt to do this problem:
But i cant graph the points.
[image: my attempt]

---

Comment: Surely plotting $a^2=4b$ is not that difficult?

Comment: You are not plotting the solutions $x$, you are plotting the points $(a,b)$ that satisfy the various conditions.

Comment: will i be looking at a = b , b< a , and b > a ?

Comment: A real root occurs twice **iff** $a^2=b$. So, plot the points $(a,b)$ that satisfy $a^2=b$. It turns out that this splits the plane into two parts, (i) $a^2>b$ and (ii) $a^2<b$.

Answer (score 1):

You've basically done all of the hard work -- it's just a matter of interpreting your results.

You've shown that the equation $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ has one solution if $b = \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$, has two solutions if $b < \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$, and has no solutions if $b > \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$.  So draw the curve $b = \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$ in blue, color below it in red, and color above it in white.